# WPF - where can I find some Resource files that will really make my datagrids stand out?

Tags: wpf, file, datagrid, resources, styles

I'd like to make my WPF datagrids really "pop" in my application. Is there a repository of really good resources files out there that I can use to apply to my datagirds? I've already used some from the silverlight toolkit but I'm sure there must be more out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use commercial datagrid. I had recently worked with Xceed in a project and we didn't got any major problem with it and it comes with several themes.

Comment: I appreciate the reply. But I'm fine with the datagrid I have now, I really just need a resource file that has the right calls to make the datagrid elements stand out. I realize xceed has resource files available, but surely there must be a repository of datagrid resource files out there for people to use.